# How to create multiple sub div tags in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is working code ,like this i want 
http://code.reloado.com/adudeq/7/edit --see pic for Output
[image: there is place between two image and add wish bottom]

i try to get the same thing using jQuery but the problem here is there is no place between two image and no add wish at the bottom

http://code.reloado.com/exesox4/3/edit#preview

[image: there is no place between two image and no add wish bottom]

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks!

Comment: click the link , there is code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make changes to you script

```
  $.each(numbers, function () {
                $(".product-loop").append("<div class='col-sm-4' id='col" +numbers[num] + "'></div>")
                $("#col" + numbers[num]).append($("<div class='product-image-wrapper' id='img-wrap" + numbers[num] + "'></div>"))
                $("#img-wrap" + numbers[num]).append($("<div class='single-products' id='singlePro" + numbers[num] + "'></div>"))
                $("#singlePro" + numbers[num]).append($("<div class='productinfo text-center' id='productCentre" + numbers[num] + "'></div>"))
                $("#productCentre" +numbers[num] ).append($("<img src='http://www.tutorialspoint.com/images/html.gif' alt=''/>\
                                              <h2>$52</h2>\
                                              <p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p>\
                                               <a href='#' class='btn btn-default add-to-cart'>\
                                               <i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i>Add to cart</a>"))
                $("#singlePro"+numbers[num] ).append($("<div class='product-overlay' id='productOverlay"+numbers[num] +"'></div>"))
                $("#productOverlay"+numbers[num] ).append($("<div class='overlay-content' id='overlayContent" + numbers[num] + "'></div>"))
                $("#overlayContent"+numbers[num] ).append($("<h2>$66</h2><p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p><a href='#' class='btn btn-default add-to-cart'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i>Add to cart</a>"))

                $("#img-wrap" + numbers[num]).append($("<div class='choose' id='chse"+ numbers[num]+"'></div>"))
                $("#chse"+numbers[num] ).append($("<ul class='nav nav-pills nav-justified'>\
                                            <li><a href=''><i class='fa fa-plus-square'></i>Add to wishlist</a></li>\
                                                <li><a href=''><i class='fa fa-plus-square'></i>Add to compare</a></li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                        "))
                num += 1;
            });
        });
```

Demo : http://code.reloado.com/ovetig3/edit#preview

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504832/how-to-get-parent-value-tables-using-jquery     ,please answer my problem

Answer (score 0):

Theres quite a lot of bad stuff going on here, id's are supposed to be unique so 6 '#productCentres' are definitely not doing you any favours.

I'm guessing that they were supposed to be in the 'product-loop' container which you missed with;

```
insertAfter(".product-loop")
```

I'm also thinking that;

```
$(".product-loop div:eq(0)")
```

was intended to tag the cart option buttons to the end of each product but since the insertAfter dumped them outside it never matched the selector.

For my own sanity I expanded the insane .each call to a function so you can better see each element being built and modify their styles/attributes as needed

I didnt include the CSS since that pushes the code sample over the character limit but i would suggest using the code below adding some padding to '.productCentre' will give you those missing gutters

```js
                function newProduct(id) {
              product = document.createElement("div");
              product.setAttribute('class', 'productCentre col-sm-4 product-image-wrapper single-products productinfo text-center');
              product.setAttribute('id', id);

              productImg = document.createElement("img");
              productImg.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com/images/html.gif');
              product.appendChild(productImg);

              productPrice = document.createElement("h2");
              productPrice.innerHTML = ('$52');
              product.appendChild(productPrice);

              productLabel = document.createElement("p");
              productLabel.innerHTML = ('Easy Polo Black Edition');
              product.appendChild(productLabel);

              productCartBtn = document.createElement("a");
              productCartBtn.class = ("btn btn-default add-to-cart");
              productCartBtn.setAttribute("href", '#');

              productCartBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart';
              product.appendChild(productCartBtn);

              productChoose = document.createElement("div");
              productChoose.setAttribute('class', "choose");

              productChooseList = document.createElement('ul');
              productChooseList.setAttribute('class', 'nav nav-pills nav-justified');
              productChooseListElement = document.createElement('li');
              productChooseListElement.innerHTML = '<a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to compare</a>';
              productChooseList.appendChild(productChooseListElement);
              productChooseListElement.innerHTML = '<a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to wishlist</a>';
              productChooseList.appendChild(productChooseListElement);
              productChoose.appendChild(productChooseList);

              product.appendChild(productChoose);

              return product;
            }

            $(function() {
              var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
              $.each(numbers, function(index) {
                $(".product-loop").append(newProduct(index));
              });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
        <div class="features_items">
          <!--features_items-->
          <h2 class="title text-center">Features Items</h2>
          <div class="product-loop">


          </div>
        </div>
        <!--features_items-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Evil Saied, you have some problems in your code. The worst is the duplicates `id`s.

If I understand you correctly, the relevant problem is that you added the classes to the wrong element (`.product-image-wrapper` for example).

**The problem**

```
$("#col").append($("<div></div>")).addClass("product-image-wrapper").attr("id","img-wrap")
```

You can see that the class `product-image-wrapper` added to the `#col` but not to the new `div` that you just create.

**The solution**

```
$("#col").append($("<div></div>").addClass("product-image-wrapper").attr("id","img-wrap"));
```

In other words, you need to move the `)` to the end.

> <sub>I removed the not relevent part of the css so I could create is as snippet, in the future, please include only the relevant code so it will easier for us to help you.</sub>

```js
$(function(){
  var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  $.each(numbers,function(){
    $("<div></div>").addClass("col-sm-4").attr("id","col").insertAfter(".product-loop");
    $("#col").append($("<div></div>").addClass("product-image-wrapper").attr("id","img-wrap"));
    $("#img-wrap").append($("<div></div>").addClass("single-products").attr("id","singlePro"));
    $("#singlePro").append($("<div></div>").addClass("productinfo text-center").attr("id","productCentre"));
    $("#productCentre").append('<img src="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/images/html.gif" alt="" />\
<h2>$52</h2>\
<p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p>\
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>')

    $(".product-loop div:eq(0)").after("<div></div>").addClass("choose").attr("id","chse");
    $("#chse").append('<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">\
<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to wishlist</a></li>\
<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to compare</a></li>\
</ul>');
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,400italic,500,700,100);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,300,600,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel);

.product-image-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #F7F7F5;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background:;
  position: relative;
  font-weight:400px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a:focus {
  outline:none;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: 300ms;
  -moz-transition: 300ms;
  -o-transition: 300ms;
  transition: 300ms;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.btn:hover, 
.btn:focus{
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #000;
}

a#scrollUp {
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #FE980F;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s ease infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s ease infinite;
}

a#scrollUp i{
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
        <div class="features_items">
          <!--features_items-->
          <h2 class="title text-center">Features Items</h2>
          <div class="product-loop">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--features_items-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/pawoce