# how to upload file to next input type file in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to upload file to next input type file ,if there is two input file , first i upload file to 1st ,next if i click on 1st input ,it should upload file to 2nd input file element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What to you mean by `upload file to 2nd input`? You can't **upload** a file to an input element..